# sqlite database not creating tables

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am having some problem while using sqlite database, and can't seem to find out the cause for the error. I have the following class

```
public class Greetings {
    //private variables
    int _id;
    String _phone_number;
    String _time;
    String _date;
    String _message;

   // Empty constructor
   public Greetings(){
   }

   // constructor
   public Greetings(int id, String date, String phone_number, String time, String message){
      this._id = id;
      this._date = date;
      this._phone_number = phone_number;
      this._time = time;
      this._message = message;
   }

   // constructor
   public Greetings(String date, String phone_number, String time, String message){
      this._date = date;
      this._phone_number = phone_number;
      this._time = time;
      this._message = message;
  }
  // getting ID
  public int getID(){
     return this._id;
  }

  // setting id
  public void setID(int id){
     this._id = id;
  }

  // getting name
  public String getDate(){
      return this._date;
  }

  // setting name
  public void setDate(String date){
      this._date = date;
  }

  // getting phone number
  public String getPhoneNumber(){
      return this._phone_number;
  }

  // setting phone number
  public void setPhoneNumber(String phone_number){
     this._phone_number = phone_number;
  }

  // getting phone number
  public String getTime(){
     return this._time;
  } 

  // setting phone number
  public void setTime(String time){
     this._time = time;
  }

  public String getMessage(){
      return this._message;
  }

  // setting phone number
  public void setMessage(String message){
     this._message = message;
  }
}
```

And the sqlitehelper class

```
public class SqliteController extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    private static final String LOGCAT = null;
    // All Static variables
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "sendGreetings";

    //  table name
    private static final String TABLE_GREETINGS = "greetings";

    // Greetings Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_DATE = "date";
    private static final String KEY_PH_NO = "phone_number";
    private static final String KEY_TIME ="time";
    private static final String KEY_MESSAGE ="message";

    public SqliteController(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        Log.d(LOGCAT,"Created");
    }

   // Creating Tables
   @Override
   public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_GREETINGS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_GREETINGS + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_DATE + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT," + KEY_TIME + "TEXT," + KEY_MESSAGE + "TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_GREETINGS_TABLE);
   }

   // Upgrading database
   @Override
   public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_GREETINGS);
       // Create tables again
       onCreate(db);
   }

   /**
     * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
     */

   // Adding new greetings
   void addGreetings(Greetings greetings) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_DATE, greetings.getDate()); // Greetings Date
        values.put(KEY_PH_NO, greetings.getPhoneNumber()); // Greetings Phone
        values.put(KEY_TIME, greetings.getTime()); //Greetings time
        values.put(KEY_MESSAGE, greetings.getMessage());

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_GREETINGS, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

    // Getting single greeting
    Greetings getGreeting(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_GREETINGS, new String[] { KEY_ID,
                    KEY_DATE, KEY_PH_NO, KEY_TIME, KEY_MESSAGE }, KEY_ID + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null)
           cursor.moveToFirst();

        Greetings greeting = new Greetings(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
            cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2),cursor.getString(3),cursor.getString(4));
        // return contact
        return greeting;
    }

    // Getting All Greetings
    public List<Greetings> getAllGreetings() {
       List<Greetings> greetingList = new ArrayList<Greetings>();
       // Select All Query
       String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_GREETINGS;

       SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
       Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

       // looping through all rows and adding to list
       if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
         do {
            Greetings greeting = new Greetings();
            greeting.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            greeting.setDate(cursor.getString(1));
            greeting.setPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(2));
            greeting.setTime(cursor.getString(3));
            greeting.setMessage(cursor.getString(4));
            // Adding contact to list
            greetingList.add(greeting);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
      }

       // return greeting list
       return greetingList;
   }

   // Updating single greeting
   public int updateGreetings(Greetings greeting) {
      SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

      ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
      values.put(KEY_DATE, greeting.getDate());
      values.put(KEY_PH_NO, greeting.getPhoneNumber());
      values.put(KEY_TIME, greeting.getTime());
      values.put(KEY_MESSAGE, greeting.getMessage());

      // updating row
      return db.update(TABLE_GREETINGS, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(greeting.getID()) });
  }

  // Deleting single greeting
  public void deleteGreetings(Greetings greeting) {
     SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
     db.delete(TABLE_GREETINGS, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(greeting.getID()) });
     db.close();
  }

  // Getting greetings Count
  public int getGreetingsCount() {
     String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_GREETINGS;
     SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
     Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
     cursor.close();

     // return count
     return cursor.getCount();
  }
}
```

Every time I execute the program by calling the following code,

```
SqliteController db = new SqliteController(this);
db.addGreetings(new Greetings(dt,txtPhoneNo,t,n));
```

I am getting the error **"table greetings has no column named message"** . Can someone help me figure out just where I am making a mistake. Thanks in advance

Comment: don´t know if this is relevant, I just see that in Your onCreate String, at  "KEY_TIME" & "KEY_MESSAGE" is no blank before "TEXT,"....

Comment: you could check your sendGreetings.db file. Maybe you need update your DATABASE_VERSION number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a space between `KEY_MESSAGE` and `KEY_TIME` and `TEXT`.So So rewrite `CREATE_GREETINGS_TABLE`  statement as

```
 String CREATE_GREETINGS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_GREETINGS + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_DATE + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT," + KEY_TIME + " TEXT," + KEY_MESSAGE + " TEXT" + ")";
```

And Don't forget to uninstall app before retry.